# How do I add MtGox ticker data to a website?

Tags: json, api, jsonp, ticker

I've tried various approaches, the current is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stage').click(function(){
jQuery.getJSON('https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=showTick',function(ticker){
            $('div#tickerbox').html(ticker)}
    )})})
```

Losing my mind . . .

Answer (score 3):

I built php tools to make this easy , providing pure text tickers, html tickers, and even image ticker( and other tools like rss ticker feeds ).

have a look at the code on : 
https://github.com/neofutur/bitcoin_simple_php_tools

more details and examples on  : 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=68205

the tools are including a 30 seconds caching system so you wont hit the api too often and thus avoid being blackisted by the anti-ddos system

I dont think javascript is the best idea to add a mtgox ticker, but if you really want it to be js, theres at least one javascript implementation, which is the firefox addon for those tickers : 
https://github.com/joric/mtgox-ticker
https://github.com/joric/mtgox-ticker/blob/master/lib/main.js

also, know that SE also have a dedicated space for bitcoin related questions : 
http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com
you could perhaps have had more answers here, where all bitcoiners are ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **the Mt. Gox API does not support JSONP nor [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) at the time of this writing**. It seems like it would be easy enough for them to add JSONP support, so if they add it in the near future, this answer should help; until then, however, this answer does not help. The rest of this answer assumes now is the future and they support JSONP.

---

First of all, you'll want to change `callback=showTick` to `callback=?` so jQuery knows to put *its* autogenerated callback name there. Then when your callback is called, `ticker` will be a decoded JSON object, not a string, so you'll want to pull the information you want out of there. For example, to show the average price:

```
jQuery.getJSON('https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
    // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
    alert(data['return'].avg.display_short);
});
```

Comment: There must be a workaround, lot's of people seem to incorporate Mt.Gox price data into their sites. Thanks.

Comment: @Kinnard: One workaround would be to use a proxy, where your server fetches the price and then gives that to the client rather than the client talking directly to Mt. Gox.