# Calling mtgox API gives JS error: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I get the following error when I try to get info from the mtgox API. In chrome I can see that using jsonp is working, and there's no cross domain errors:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?',
  async: false,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(json) {
       console.log('ok');
  }
});
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't seem to have any syntax errors.

Comment: It doesn't, but when you request it I get a syntax error...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add MtGox ticker data to a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189296/how-do-i-add-mtgox-ticker-data-to-a-website)